# Adding a Converter to a ResourceDictionary Programmatically

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary, staticresource, converters

To save having to write the syntax `<converters:MyConverter x:Key="myConverter"/>` in a Resources section of XAML in every control I want to use a converter as a static resource, I had the idea to try add every converter in the scope of that control to its resource dictionary programmatically.

What I have done is to create my own custom `ControlBase` class which derives from `UserControl` which I would then inherit any of my custom controls from rather than `UserControl`.  `ControlBase` is responsible for loading any resources (converters, images, template selectors, etc.) in its own assembly and a MediaLibrary into the `Resources` property of itself.  It also has a protected method called `LoadCallerResources(ResourceTypes resourceTypes)` which loads any resources of the specified types from the derived control into the `Resources` dictionary.

The method which is core to all this functionality is as follows.  Note that I am using several of my own extension methods and supplementary methods in this code such as "AsEnumerable" on the ResourceTypes flags enum, "ThrowArgumentNullExceptionIfNull", "ToCamelCase" and "GetResourceTypePlurals" used to get the plural name of each resource type on the provided enum (which corresponds to the directory the resources of that type are expected to be in).

```
/// <summary>
/// Loads all .g.resources files found within the provided assembly that meet the requirements for the specified resource type into the <see cref="FrameworkElement.Resources"/> collection.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="resourceTypes">The type of data in the .g.resources files to load.</param>
/// <param name="resourceAssembly">The assembly to load the resources from.</param>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">Thrown if resourceAssembly is null.</exception>
private void LoadAssemblyResources(ResourceTypes resourceTypes, Assembly resourceAssembly)
{
    Stream manifestResourceStream = resourceAssembly
        .ThrowArgumentNullExceptionIfNull(nameof(resourceAssembly))
        .GetManifestResourceStream(resourceAssembly.GetName().Name + ".g.resources");

    if (manifestResourceStream != null)
        using (ResourceReader resourceReader = new ResourceReader(manifestResourceStream))
            foreach (DictionaryEntry relevantDictionaryEntry in resourceReader
                .Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
                .Where(dictionaryEntry =>
                {
                    string resourceFilePath = dictionaryEntry.Key.ToString();
                    string resourceDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(dictionaryEntry.Key.ToString());
                    string resourceFileName = Path.GetFileName(resourceFilePath);

                    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(resourceDirectory) && string.Equals(Path.GetExtension(resourceFileName), ".baml", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && resourceTypes.AsEnumerable().Any(resourceType => resourceFileName.StartsWith(Enum.GetName(typeof(ResourceTypes), resourceType), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        || GetResourceTypesPlurals(resourceTypes).Any(resourceTypePlural => resourceDirectory.Contains(resourceTypePlural, CompareInfo.GetCompareInfo(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Name), false));
                }))
                    Resources.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(relevantDictionaryEntry.Key.ToString()).ToCamelCase(), relevantDictionaryEntry.Value);
}
```

There are a few issues I am having with this code:

1. The resources come in as all lowercase whilst their source files are named in Pascal Case (which I would like to convert into Camel Case)
2. `StaticResource` bindings to the converters, even when spelt in all -lowercase lettering, give the compiler error of 'The resource "myconvertername" could not be resolved.'
3. In order for a converter (.cs file) to be found in .g.resources, its build action must be changed from "Compile" to "Resource" - doesn't this mean that the code will mean anything when used as a static resource anyway?

My ultimate goal is to be able to reference static resources in XAML without having to explicitly declare them in the dictionary of the control.  How would I do this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just put your converters in the application's resources (App.xaml) instead?  That makes them available everywhere, and you only need to list them once.

Comment: Or derive your converters from `MarkupExtension` instead: `{Binding Foo, Converter={conv:SomeRandomConverter}}`. But just do what Bradley says.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Doesn't this mean having to duplicate my converters used by certain controls for every separate application they are used in though?

Comment: I didn't realize you were trying to stop duplication across *applications*, you only mentioned *controls*. In that case, yes, you would still need to declare them once per application.  You could always have a loose resource dictionary that you keep updated and include once in each application though.

Comment: Ah, so an App.xaml which merges in all the converters from all of the control libraries?  I'm not sure how that would be performance-wise having all that available at every level of the application but as long as I am strongly referencing all of the views I use I could see that working.  Ideally I'm moving towards runtime-swappable views using Prism regions though so I'm thinking it might be best if I separate all my converters from their views into independent assemblies now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > To save having to write the syntax  in a Resources section of XAML

The approach i favor for this situation is to have my converters implement MarkupExtension.  Doing so makes it so that you don't need to declare it as a resource in Xaml.

```
  public class InvertedBooleanConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
      return null; //put logic here
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
      return null; //put logic here
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
      return this;
    }
  }
```

You can then use it as such in xaml:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding someValue, Converter={yourNamespace:InvertedBooleanConverter}}"
```

Comment: This approach is probably the best-suited for my codebase as it allows the converters to remain decoupled from the main application and stay local to the scope in which they are needed.  I am curious why you didn't assign to the static field as an initializer to save having the `if` check and assignment inside `ProvideValue` though, is there a problem with doing this?

Comment: Actually, to add to my last question, wouldn't it be possible to just have `return this;` instead of having a static field?

Comment: Both are excellent points.  I've been reusing this templtate for many years now and never thought to look closer at the code.  I agree with both.

Comment: Do custom markup extensions work in the designer?  I am currently getting "The type 'myNamespace:MyConverter' was not found.  Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built".  The namespace and converter name are correct so my only thought is that the designer isn't aware of MarkupExtensions through project references or within the XAML's own assembly.  Where is your Converter class relative to the XAML which uses it and how is it referenced?